# Upgrade from 4.0 to 2011 workflows canceled

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, upgrade, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

So after upgrading from 4.0 to 2011 some workflows have been canceled and here's the error message when viewing the details.

> Workflow instance cancelled during upgrade because it cannot be
>   deserialized. A possible reason for this failure is a workflow
>   referencing a custom activity that has been unregistered

Searching turns up zilch.

Looking in the database the above message is in the `friendlyname` column and checking the `message` column, where the full error is stored is `null`.

I would like to know if/how I can restart them to pickup where they left off?

Comment: silly questions: do your workflows use custom activites?  if they do were they re-registerd when you upgraded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer no, once a workflow is cancelled it stops and cannot be re-started.  However, if you fix the problem you can re-run them from the begining.

EDIT: you need to re-register and possibly make changes to your plugins before you can do this then.